# How to generate random number and print shiny if equals

Tags: javascript, object, math, random, methods

I am learning to code and I am currently stuck on JavaScript object methods. I am trying to write a code to print 'shiny' if the random number generates = 5. How can I achieve that? Also, is it printing undefined which I do not know where it is coming from. Thank you for reading.

```
const pokemonGoCommunityDay = {

  wildEncounters: ['machop','roselia','swablu','gible','snivy','fletchling'],

  currentEncounter() {

    while (this.currentEncounter) {
      this.currentEncounter = this.wildEncounters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
      console.log(this.currentEncounter);

      if (/* How to make it generate a certain number and if =5 log shiny*/ === 5){
        console.log('Shiny!');
      }break;
    }
  }
}  
console.log(pokemonGoCommunityDay.currentEncounter());
```

Answer (score 0):

You already had the necessary piece in your code :)

Here's how you can do it:

```
if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)==5){
  console.log('Shiny!');
}
```

Comment: Thank for you your help. I am getting undefined but do not know where it is coming from.